# gcloud builds submit with a fatal: not a git repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Go [Dockerfile](https://github.com/kaihendry/count/blob/gcp-cloudrun/Dockerfile) from https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy with a one line change so that I can tell what version I'm running:

```
RUN go build -ldflags "-X main.Version=$(git describe --always)" -mod=readonly -v -o server
```

When I build locally via `docker build .` and test, there is **no problem** with `git describe`, however if I submit the Docker to be built via `gcloud builds submit` it [fails](https://github.com/kaihendry/count/runs/1660868727?check_suite_focus=true) with:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How do I build my Cloud Run docker image so it has this Git version reference?

Answer (score 2):

When you perform `gcloud builds submit`, all the project files aren't sent to Cloud Build. The command take into account your `.gitignore` file and the `.gcloudignore` file. If you haven't a `.gcloudignore` a default behavior is enforced in addition of the `.gitignore` file directive. More detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)

So, to fix this, create a `.gcloudignore` file with only the file to exclude for your Build. So, let the `.git/` (don't add it in the file) and it will work.

Comment: I don't quite follow, I want .git there, so I need to put that in the .gcloudignore file? That isn't making a lot of sense to me, but I've been drinking.

Comment: Yes, by default, the `.git` dir is ignored. If you want it, you have to override the `.gcloudignore` file. Create one, even empty. You will see, it works!